Where is the A/C relay for a 2007 Monte Carlo SS
Where is the air conditioning relay for my 2007 Monte Carlo SS? The A/C works but produces a clicking sound for about two minutes before stopping. The A/C still works

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Are you in your car hearing a relay clicking (inside or outside), or is it the ac compressor clutch disengaging and engaging repeatedly that you're hearing until ac stops cooling? Can you open the hood and observe the compressor while ac runs and listen to where clicking is emanating from? The ac relay powers the compressor clutch and can cycle on/off along with the clutch that may indicate a different problem to a faulty relay. You can substitute the relay with another one (windshield wiper relay or similar one in the fuse panel).

This fuse box is under the hood of your car. It should have a cover on top of it which will be in the same general shape. I've circled the relay for the AC.

